# Can't update attribut in python classes

Tags: python, class, object

Here is a part of what I've done :

```
class Something(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._loader = 100

    def _get_loader(self):
        return self._loader

    def _set_loader(self, val):
        self._loader = self._loader+val

    loader = property(_get_loader, _set_loader)

    def fire(self):
        fired = random.randint(1, 21)
        self.loader = self.loader-fired
        print("Bullets remaining : {}".format(self.loader))

M = Something()
M.fire()
```

The attribute self.loader in fire method don't update as I want. Instead of doing loader-fired, it does loader-something. I want to minus loader by the fired value, but it did not as I want. It displays an increasing value each time I call fire()

Comment: If course the value increases, that's what the `self._loader = self._loader+val` in your setter function is doing...

Comment: I changed it, now it displays the value fired but negative ...

Comment: Getters and setters don't really make sense for this simple use case. It is just class clutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is located at the "setter":

```
def _set_loader(self, val):
    self._loader = self._loader + val
```

Here you this *add* the `val` to the `self._loader`, given you set it as `self.loader = val`. So if you write:

```
self.loader = self.loader-fired
```

with `self.loader` for example `100`, and fired `3`, then `self.loader-fired` is `97`, and by *setting* `self.loader`, you thus will add `97` to the `self_loader` value.

A setter typically has the shape:

```
def _set_loader(self, val):
    self._loader = val
```

So your code should look like:

```
class Something(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._loader = 100

    def _get_loader(self):
        return self._loader

    def _set_loader(self, val):
        self._loader = val

    loader = property(_get_loader, _set_loader)

    def fire(self):
        fired = random.randint(1, 21)
        self.loader = self.loader-fired
        print("Bullets remaining : {}".format(self.loader))
```

A potential problem here is that if you keep calling `.fire()`, eventually the `_loader` will obtain a value *below* zero. You thus might want to use `max(0, ...)` here to prevent that:

```
def _set_loader(self, val):
    self._loader = max(0, val)
```

You also might want to raise an error in case you call `.fire()` and the number of bullets is zero, since I assume that you can not fire without bullets.

Comment: Oh thanks, it works. Actually the work isn't finish, it is just a part. I already have a solution when it somes to 0 bullets.